Firefox won't close when trying to close last tab
Firefox has stopped closing when I try to close the last tab. Instead, I now have to manually click the x in the top right corner (1), instead of middle-clicking the tab, or clicking the tab's own x on the right-hand side (2).

I have already checked in about:config to see that browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab is already set to true as mentioned here.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Is it a bug in a recent Firefox version? I have Firefox installed from manually downloading it, rather than from the snap store, so I don't know if that is affecting things.

setting   browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab   to true solved this for me

This was my own fault. For some reason Firefox was always asking me for my "master password" when I opened the first window, and I just kept hitting cancel, thinking it was odd, and that I would deal with it another time. In the end I gave up and put my master password in and this issue went away. Firefox has also since stopped asking me for the master password. I'm guessing this all has to do with some update that wen't through. At least this post may help others if they come across the same wierd issue.

I'm not seeing what you describe and, I have a manually installed firefox on Ubuntu 24.04.  It could be something about your firefox profile so, try a different profile.  Perhaps a new profile?
Firefox profiles can be created with the terminal command
firefox -P  

After creating a new profile, try using it. That can be done with the terminal command
firefox -P [whatever you named the new profile]  

